# Why would a tube radio leave the 6.3V heater tap on the transformer disconnected?

Tags: transformer, radio, vacuum-tube

I'm attempting to repair a Clarion C104 tube radio. I started the repair years ago, put it away, and now I'm giving it another attempt. When I started the repair, the transformer (Clarion part no. C80-223) was damaged, so I replaced it with an equivalent transformer (Hammond Manufacturing part no. 270DX).
[image: clarion transformer]
[image: Hammond transformer]
[image: Transformer windings]

Unfortunately, several of the transformer wires have become disconnected between then and now, and I'm attempting to reconnect them correctly.

I understand that many tubes use a heater voltage of 6.3V--thus the 6.3V output on the Filament #2 winding. However, the Sam's PhotoFacts schematic for this radio seems to show the Filament #2 winding disconnected:

[image: Sam's Schematic]

I'm assuming that the lower winding in the schematic is Filament #1 since the 5Y3GT rectifier tube has a filament voltage of 5.0V:
[image: 5Y3GT Spec]

Why does this radio leave the 6.3V tap disconnected?

In asking that question, I'm making assumptions. Perhaps these questions need to be answered first:

- Am I correct in interpreting the stub on the upper tap of the transformer in the PhotoFacts schematic as indicating that it's disconnected?
- Why did they ground the other leg of the upper tap if the entire tap is unused?
- Why are there two loops on the 5.0 V tap in the PhotoFacts schematic and one loop on the 6.3 V tap? Shouldn't it be the other way around? Did I misinterpret which tap is which?

Comment: That looks like it might be an arrow-head on the end of that transformer tap, which I would be inclined to interpret as something along the lines of "we all know where this goes and we don't want to clutter up the schematic by drawing it in everywhere."

Comment: @brhans Ah. OK. Looking at the schematic again, I see that pin 7 (one of the heater pins) on every other tube has no connection on the schematic. Perhaps it goes there.

Comment: Notice the loudspeaker has an electro-magnetic.

Comment: And the wonderful old symbol for electrolytic condensers (capacitors) like components 7 and 8 in the rectifier section

Comment: One side of ALL the heaters  is grounded, but all of the others are disconnected.  That clearly is deliberate.  I know nothing about vacuum tubes, but I'd wire it up just as drawn.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat did you read brhans comment - valves (tubes) don't work without heaters!

Comment: @brhans Please make your comment into an answer.  It's 100% correct.

Comment: @Chu I read it, but ALL are disconnected.  They show a loop of wire adjacent to the word loop.  They show a 6.3V tap without a connection.  My initial approach would be to hook it all up as drawn and then use a trial and error approach to connect up the heaters as required.  If there was an **implied connection**, there would be something.  Tubes are more art form than science.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Heaters provide the electron cloud that's fundamental  to tube operation, either directly or by heating a cathode, they are not optional. Omitting their connections on circuit diagrams was as commonplace as not showing the power supply lines on op-amp circuits today.

Comment: I concede defeat.  But it's easy for the OP, if the second heater connection is connected to all, then brhans has the truth of it.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat The second heater connection is laying disconnected on my workbench right now. Had a used better wire labels (most have fallen off by now) or taken a photo before I removed the old transformer, I'd know for certain where the second heater connection went.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That looks like it might be an arrow-head on the end of that transformer tap, which I would be inclined to interpret as something along the lines of "we all know where this goes and we don't want to clutter up the schematic by drawing it in everywhere."

So in this instance, I believe that you're intended to connect that tap on the transformer to all of the heater filaments.

Comment: Would it be safe to say that, "we all know this goes to the tube filaments", given that this is a schematic for a tube radio? Or is it better to leave that conclusion as an exercise for the reader of this question / answer?

Comment: Since every heater (OK except the rectifier) has one grounded pin and one unconnected, this is certainly the answer.

Comment: @brhans I'll accept your answer either way, but do you think your answer would be better if you added that this is the heater connection for the rest of the tubes?

Answer (score 0):

The "arrow" symbol is an Earth/Ground symbol. It means that all of those points are connected to a (common) ground.  On an old radio, the "common ground" is probably the steel chassis frame: if there is no metal chassis frame, it would be wired: in modern electronics it would have to be a pcb track and pour:

Comment: I really don't see how this is an answer to the question. The "arrow" that is refered to in brhans's answer is not the "ground" arrow you seem to refer to (which would be pretty obvious for anyone familiar with electronics), but the (thin) arrow that's at the end of one of the transformer taps in the schematic.